# Is it valid to send consecutive tcp packets having overlapping data?

Tags: tcp

Assuming:

- TCP Window Size of client: 2000 bytes
- MSS (maximum segment size) of client: 1500 bytes

Now server want to send 3000 bytes to client `B1..B3000`. Server sends:

- Packet-1: Contains `B1..B1500` bytes, `SeqNo: 1`, `Length: 1500`
- Packet-2: Contains `B501..B2000` bytes, `SeqNo: 501`, `Length: 1500`

So in effect:

```
Data       B1....B501....B1500....B2000....B3000
Packet-1   B1....B501....B1500
Packet-2         B501....B1500....B2000
```

Is it valid and allowed by TCP protocol?

Comment: Valid but also pointless. If the first packet arrives you're just repeating yourself, and if it doesn't you're out of sequence and liable to have the packet rejected and have to resend it.

Comment: I also think so but Windows Server 2016 is doing it and it is giving me a lot of pain... Because the device at receiving end doesn't like this and they close the connection.

Comment: That won't be the cause. It would violate RFC 793. But I would have a look at the ACKs. The server won't be doing that for no reason.

Comment: Here is a quick screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l2Lo.png